# How to fix boolean method in string

Tags: java

Imagine you are developing a software package for Amazon.com that requires users to enter their own passwords. Your software requires that users’ passwords meet the following requirements: The password should be at least 8 characters. The password should contain at least one uppercase and at least one lowercase letter. The password should contain at least one digit. The password may not contain a blank
Write a program that verifies that passwords are valid.

This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class assignment7{

public static boolean test(String password,Scanner input){
boolean valid=false;
while(input.hasNextLine()){
  password=input.nextLine();
  for(int i=0;i<password.length();i++){
    char c=password.charAt(i);
  if((password.length()>=8)&&
     (Character.isUpperCase(c))&&
     (Character.isLowerCase(c))&&
     (Character.isDigit(c))&&
     (Character.isWhitespace(c)))
    valid=true;
}
}
return valid;
}

public static void main(String[]args)throws FileNotFoundException{
Scanner input=new Scanner(new File("password.txt"));
String password;
while(input.hasNextLine()){
password=input.nextLine();
System.out.println(password.trim());
boolean isvalid=test(password,input);
if(isvalid)
  System.out.println("This is a valid password: "+password+"\n");
else
  System.out.println("This is a invalid password: "+password+"\n");
}
System.out.println("This program prcoessed all data");
input.close();
}
}
```

Why does my code only read the first password and stop executing? Plus even my password is correct but it still print out invalid password?

My input file is:

```
asdF1k12

Mzj1kada45

jKl123oin
```

Comment: "plus even my password is correct but it still print out invalid passowrd?" Check the logic in your test() method. You are using all logical AND (`&&`) operators to check to see that it meets your valid password condition. How could a character be uppercase AND lowercase AND a digit AND whitespace? It can't be. So if you want to check to see they are at least one of these things, you should be using the logical OR operator (`||`). Also, what would happen if every character is an invalid one, but the last one is valid? `valid` would get set true and test() would return so, even though its not.

Comment: @JamieTaylorSangerman I see now, but why my code stop at first password and not going to second password. is my main have some problem

Comment: It is hard to tell without knowing the contents of `password.txt`. Does the file contains any newlines? edit: the answer by @rgettman seems to have found the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have create a `while` loop to loop through the lines in two locations: in your `main` method and in your `test` method.  The `test` method is consuming all input, leaving nothing more for the `main` loop.

You're already passing `password` to `test` correctly; just don't have a `while` loop within `test`.

You don't need to check the password length each loop; just test it once before the `for` loop on the characters.

A character cannot simultaneously be uppercase, lowercase, a digit, *and* (`&&`) whitespace.  You'll need to test if it's uppercase, lowercase, *or* (`||`) a digit, which would make it not whitespace.

Right now you're setting `valid` to `true` if any of the characters meet the conditions.  To make it so that `valid` is `true` if all of the characters meet the requirements, initialize `valid` to `true` and set it to `false` if the current character doesn't meet the requirement.

You may also decide not test empty lines at all depending on your exact requirements.